# Kotlin write byte array to BufferedWriter socket

Tags: android, kotlin

What I'm trying to is sending bytes to TCP socket.
Data format is byte array.

But `BufferedWrite.write()` doesn't have ByteArray.  It has `int` or `CharArray` or `String`
Here is my code.

```
    socket = Socket("192.168.9.34", 5000)
    networkReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket!!.getInputStream()))
    networkWriter = BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(socket!!.getOutputStream()))

    val json = """
        {"type":"REQ","code":"DP1200","key":"e7aa7f5e-15df-4ea1-9e7b-e4f05d2ac288","ip":"192.168.9.33","port":"31147","serviceid":"WINIXRND1D"}
    """.trimIndent()
    val jsonByte = json.toString().toByteArray()
    val header: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(0x76,0x31,0x30,0x30,0x0,0x0,0x0,jsonByte.size.toByte())
    val payload: ByteArray = header + jsonByte 
    try {
        networkWriter!!.write(payload)  //<== I want to write byte arra here!  but write's argument no ByteArray
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
```

Please, correct give me advices.

Comment: afaik, BufferedReader and Writer works with newLine characters. Also, `val payload: ByteArray = jsonByte + header` i don't know if it will work. 1.) I could not found Operator overloading for ByteArray 2.)you are suffixing header instead of prefixing it.

Comment: you can use `ByteArrayOutputStream` from java or its kotlin analogous if you like.

Comment: @RahulKumar Thanks for your comment.  Is it possible to convert ByteArray to CharArray? It's not easy for me using ByteArrayOutPutStream.

Comment: you can convert bytearry to charArray but you have to understand a few things. All bytes are not char. Also the sizeof char can vary from system to system but size of byte won't. I have messed up these things in past and its never really good to figure out the bug.